# What to use instead of base object in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I would like to do something like this in c++ (but I cant since there is no "baseobject" like in for example JAVA)

```
double integrate(double(*integrand)(InputData, int), vector<BaseObject>& inputdata){
   ...
   for(...)
       value+= integrand(inputdata, someIntVariable);
   ...
   return value;
}
```

where I have put different types of objects in `inputData` that shuold be input for my `integrand`-function. I then can just cast these values inside my integrand-functions

```
double integrand1(vector<BaseObject> &inputdata, int s){
     double d = (double) inputdata.at(1);
     char s = (char ) inputdata.at(2);
     ... do stuff with d ans s
}
```

How can I accomplish this in some other way?

**Edit** I understand why it is not a good idee to pass a vector by value, I just wanted to show that I need a collection of different data for different integrands.

I can explain what my goal with the function is: I want to do a general integration-function, so I can can pass a general "integrand" that my function then integrates numerically. However, different integrands needs completely different input data (say maybe some need 4x4 matrices etc).

Comment: A way to accomplish that is type erasure, but I feel you might be asking the wrong question. Why do you even want to put unrelated types into one container? Do they have anything in common? Is there a closed set of those types? Casting is error prone and opens your program for bad behaviour, because the compiler can't verify that the values actually carry what you expect them to.

Comment: True Java programmer: `vector` is passed by copy, not by reference!

Comment: @Ajay that's not a problem on its own. Frankly, there's so little specified in this answer that it's impossible to tell what should be done here.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, Hey, why are you advocating the OP, who hasn't replied to anyone? CheerS!

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I want to do a general integration-function, so I can can pass a general "integrand" that my function then integrates numerically. However, different integrands needs completely different inputData (say maybe some need 4x4 matrices etc).

Comment: If your integrands need completely different input data, how do you know what to pass into an integrand?

Comment: You can do this by: 1. varadic template 2.`tuple` 3. creating a common base class for your objects. But you can't put different types in a `vector` except by `void*` or `char*` and at that point they have lost all type information.

Answer (score 0):

In java anything more complex than an int is a reference. In C++ objects are not references by default. This makes it impossible to store different objects in a vector since each object type will require a different ammount of space to store it (vectors store objects contiguously).

To achive what you want you will have to use pointers (a more generalized version of a reference since you can perform pointer maths on a pointer). There is nothing wrong with using a vector of void* but you are probably better off using a common base class for all the objects you want to store in the vector since you will need some way to find out the type before you can process your objects (C++ has very limited RTTI).

Comment: No, you don't need to directly use pointers. A common base class won't work for primitive types.

Comment: Since different type will have different storage requirements, it is impossible to store different types in the same vectors since vectors allocate the same amount of storage per item, so for different type you will be forced to use pointers.

Comment: yes, but you don't have to use them *directly*. A `variant` type is an example of such an abstraction that *doesn't involve pointers* (hides the usage in its implementation), and is used like every other value type. I think that "you will have to use pointers" is a misleading statement to make.

Comment: variants will either use pointers internally or allocate space based on the needs of the biggest type (the C equivalent of a union). Variants also cannot use user defined types.

Comment: "variants also cannot use user defined types" - are we talking about the same `variant` concept? I was talking about `boost::variant` or upcoming `std::variant`, which *most certainly* can accomodate both UDTs and base types. And I've already mentioned that the internal use in them isn't important in my criticism of your expression. `std::vector` also uses pointers internally, but I'd never say that in order to use `std::vector`, you "have to use pointers".

Comment: since boost::variant uses templates, you can use UDT but you need to exhaustively specify what types variant can handle at compile time, pointers have full runtime polymorphism so do not have this limitation and will behave more similarly to the way Java behaves.

Answer (score -1):

Use [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html).

```
vector<boost::any> inputdata
```

Comment: I have downvoted your answer because I don't believe this question can be appropriately answered before the OP answers my comment. Right now it's just a guess, and it's neigh impossible to tell what's the actual goal here.

Answer (score -2):

The C++ way to do this is with templates:

```
template<typename integrand_type, typename inputdata_type>
double integrate(integrand_type &&integrand, const inputdata_type &inputdata){
   ...
   for(...)
       value+= integrand(inputdata, someIntVariable);
   ...
   return value;
}
```

... assuming `inputdata` should be a constant container of some sorts. Also, you do understand that passing a vector by value, as a function parameter, makes a complete copy of the vector, right? That's why you need a reference.

Java objects are completely different from C++ objects. In Java, when you reference an object you are really referencing a pointer to an object. All objects in Java are references. In C++ you have to be explicit as to what you want, otherwise you will end up producing terribly inefficient code.

Comment: This answer completely avoids actually answering the question, and answers a different one that hasn't been asked. You're sacrificing dynamic runtime polymorphism that's possible with what OP presented and asked for.

Comment: This seems to be a good solution. But I guess i have to create a different container "inputdata_type", for each "integrand" i make?

Comment: Your container's type will correspond to each integrand you make, yes. C++'s type checking will enforce that all your types are correct. Your code will not even compile, if your types are wrong. In Java, using base objects, you won't find out that you screwed up until run time.